# Is there a way to resize an image once it is returned from an aws bucket

Tags: reactjs, image, amazon-s3, resize, blob

I am trying to use `react-image-file-resizer` and I have it working in some parts of my application but I am now trying to handle a response from the aws server of the image. The format is changed and the error I get is `item is not type BLOB` is there a way I can convert the url returned from the aws server to a type BLOB?

This is the component i am working with :

```
const Items = ({ orgList }) => {
  const [logos, setLogos] = useState()
  
  const resizeImage = (image) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    Resizer.imageFileResizer(
      image,
      200,
      200,
      "JPEG",
      100,
      0,
      (uri) => {
        resolve(uri);
      },
      "base64"
    );
  });

  const imageHelper = async (image) => {
    const sizing = await resizeImage(image)
    setLogos(sizing)
  }

  return (
    <>
      {orgList.items ? (
        <div>
          {orgList.items.map((item) => (
            <Card key={item.orgID} className="w-100 m-2">
              <CardHeader className="d-flex">
                <Link to={`/monitoring-orgs/${item.orgID}`}>{item.name}</Link>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>
                <Row>
                  <Col md="5">
                    <dl>
                      <dt>GroupID</dt>
                      <dd>{item.GroupID || "-"}</dd>
                      <dt>Logo</dt>
                      <dd>
                        {imageHelper(item.logoURL)}
                        {!item.logoURL ? (
                          "No logo uploaded"
                        ) : (
                          <img src={logos} alt={"company logo"} />
                        )}
                      </dd>
                    </dl>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md="5">
                    <dl>
                      <dt>OrgID</dt>
                      <dd>{item.orgID}</dd>
                      <dt>Enabled</dt>
                      <dd>{item.enabled ? "Yes" : "No"}</dd>
                    </dl>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="buttonSpinner">
          <Spinner />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Items);
```

Comment: the `console.log("^&*()", typeof image)` takes up the whole body of the `resizeImage` function. So, *currently*, the `new Promise` is called on render of the  `Items` and not when the `resizeImage` is called.

Comment: Oh yes I shouldve taken that out. I dont get the error `parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'` with that console in there. I will remove it for review.

Comment: Also the description of the package you use, mentions:
"**React module that can rescale local images.**"
Your image is not local.

Comment: Ah I see. Okay so I've chosen the wrong package thanks for the insight that is very helpful